# How to set specific Sec-WebSocket-Key in Client's WebSocket opening handshake message using autobahn android library?

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

I want to set custom/specific Sec-WebSocket-Key in Client's Websocket opening handshake message. I am using Autobahn Android library for creating websocket in android.

I could connect to local Autobahn Python server example using provided Android example app code for Websocket. But I am unable to connect custom server which needs specific Sec-WebSocket-Key for opening a connection(I think it's not mandatory to have a particular Sec-WebSocket-Key for a server but still..)

so is there any way to set this specific key in Client's websocket opening handshake message using any of the autobahn android api method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebSocket spec (RFC6455) *requires* a compliant client to generate a *random* key on each and every connection.

A server that mandates a specific key isn't spec compliant. There are no hooks in AutobahnAndroid to set a specific key (and we won't add such things). Please fix your server or use a compliant one.

You can find the code for generating news keys [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketWriter.java#L124).